# If an URL is clicked manually and opens a new tab, is there anyway for the opened tab to get a reference to the window where the URL was clicked?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I intended:
1. The user clicks an URL on a window and it opens in a new tab (the newly opened tab has the same domain as the original window).
2. The opened tab sends a message (using `postMessage`) to the original window where the user clicked the URL.

Unfortunately, the opened tab can't get a reference to the original window. I've tried `window.opener` and it did not work. It seems that most methods would only work if the tab is opened using `window.open`.

I've considered making the original window sends a message to the opened tab. That way the new tab could get a reference to the original window using `event.source`. So far I can make the original window detect when the user clicks the URL by adding `onclick` to the URL, but it doesn't fire if the user opens the URL by pressing the scroll wheel, and I also can't figure out a way to make the original window get a reference to the opened tab.

Comment: What would you like to see happen if the user copies the link URL and pastes it into the URL bar of a new tab? What about on a different web browser? I suspect that you're trying to do something that's fundamentally impossible here, but it may be possible to accomplish your goal using a different mechanism. For example, perhaps the two browser windows can communicate by sending XHRs to a common server-side endpoint.

Comment: Copying URL is outside of my target so it doesn't matter, and I also think that's impossible to detect without adding a specialized string to the URL.

Comment: @RayArfin: What is your target? I suspect adding a token of some kind into the URL (and then establishing communication outside of the browser) is likely going to be necessary.

Comment: For example, on a mobile browser inside a captive webview on Android, I will often open new links by a long press and the "Open in <browser>" intent, which seems like it would break your application here. As a general rule, you shouldn't require that the user must use any specific feature of their browser, since that will likely break accessibility.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Despite saying "the user", I actually intended this for my personal use, so the script will only have to take into account my preference. My intended target is for the script to fire if I click the URL (either left-click or scroll-click, but preferably scroll-click). Others may still get a useful insight from this question though.

Comment: I trust you read this article? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @C.vanDorsten Not that particular one, but I've read others and did not find anything helpful, so I'm trying to find a workaround. I'll try reading it though, in case I got an inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on a link with the `rel` attribute set to `opener`, the `window.opener` property is set on the new tab or window. From there you can call a function that is defined on that window.

```js
// first tab:
window.sendMessage = function (data) {
  // handle message
}

// new tab
window.opener.sendMessage(data)
```